# PowerShell Add-Member ScriptMethod - cannot set variable value

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to set the variable value inside the script method which I try to attach to an object using `Add-Member`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$a = "old value";
$obj = New-Object -TypeName "System.Object"
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -Name Info -Value { param($msg) $a = $msg; } -MemberType ScriptMethod
$obj.Info("123");
Write-Host "a = $a";
```

I expected output to be `a = 123` but I see `a = old value`. I think the issue is related to scoping (inside the script method, $a must mean a different variable since the value is not maintained). How do I set the value of the $a variable that I already have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the [Scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

If you make `$a` a global `$global:a` or give it a script scope `$script:a` the below works:

```
$script:a = "old value"
$obj = New-Object -TypeName "System.Object"
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -Name Info -Value { param($msg) $script:a = $msg; } -MemberType ScriptMethod
$obj.Info("123")

Write-Host "a = $script:a"
```

Output:

> a = 123